# How to add a body class for the current node's taxonomy to a Drupal 7 theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

Does anyone know how or can guide me in the right direction on how to add a body css class for the current node's taxonomy term?  i.e. `<body class="term-dogs">` where "dogs" is the taxonomy term name.  It could also be just the term ID.  Either way is fine I just need a solution.  This will be for a Drupal 7 zen sub-theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer took longer than I expected to figure out. The hard part was collecting the terms on the node, since [All taxonomy functions relating to nodes have been removed or refactored](http://drupal.org/update/modules/6/7#taxonomy_node). Ultimately, page 355 of Pro Drupal 7 Development saved the day with a snippet that does the job previously handled by taxonomy_node_get_terms.

Below is the code that worked for me (look for the part that says "MAGIC BEGINS HERE"). Assuming you're creating a sub-theme of Zen, you'll want to move this to your sub-theme's template.php file and rename it to YOURSUBTHEMENAME_preprocess_html:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the html template.
 *
 * @param $vars
 *   An array of variables to pass to the theme template.
 * @param $hook
 *   The name of the template being rendered ("html" in this case.)
 */
function zen_preprocess_html(&$vars, $hook) {
  // If the user is silly and enables Zen as the theme, add some styles.
  if ($GLOBALS['theme'] == 'zen') {
    include_once './' . drupal_get_path('theme', 'zen') . '/zen-internals/template.zen.inc';
    _zen_preprocess_html($vars, $hook);
  }

  // Classes for body element. Allows advanced theming based on context
  // (home page, node of certain type, etc.)
  if (!$vars['is_front']) {
    // Add unique class for each page.
    $path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']);
    // Add unique class for each website section.
    list($section, ) = explode('/', $path, 2);
    if (arg(0) == 'node') {
      if (arg(1) == 'add') {
        $section = 'node-add';
      }
      elseif (is_numeric(arg(1)) && (arg(2) == 'edit' || arg(2) == 'delete')) {
        $section = 'node-' . arg(2);
      }
      // MAGIC BEGINS HERE
      $node = node_load(arg(1));
      $results = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags', array('default'));
      foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
          $vars['classes_array'][] = strtolower($result['#title']);
        }
      }
      // MAGIC ENDS HERE
    }
    $vars['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('section-' . $section);
  }
  if (theme_get_setting('zen_wireframes')) {
    $vars['classes_array'][] = 'with-wireframes'; // Optionally add the wireframes style.
  }
  // Store the menu item since it has some useful information.
  $vars['menu_item'] = menu_get_item();
  switch ($vars['menu_item']['page_callback']) {
    case 'views_page':
      // Is this a Views page?
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'page-views';
      break;
    case 'page_manager_page_execute':
    case 'page_manager_node_view':
    case 'page_manager_contact_site':
      // Is this a Panels page?
      $vars['classes_array'][] = 'page-panels';
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome. I am now thinking about a module that will make that possible without coding. You know, to make the Drupal world a better place for the next generation. I would add that you can make this more bullet proof by also adding classes like taxonomy-term-id-<tid> or tag-<tid> where <tid> is the actual term id of the taxonomy term. This will avoid "Oopsies" when you are dealing with localized taxonomy terms using one single term id and a term name that is translated using the Drupal's interface translation.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to know how to do this and Matt V's solution worked perfectly. I made a couple of additions to his work. I called drupal_html_class which replaces spaces and invalid characters. And I added in the term ID to allow you to target a term even if the name of the term changes.

```
// MAGIC BEGINS HERE
$node = node_load(arg(1));
$results = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_tags', array('default'));
foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
    // Call drupal_html_class to make safe for a css class (remove spaces, invalid characters)
    $vars['classes_array'][] = "taxonomy-" . strtolower(drupal_html_class( $result['#title']) );
    // Add taxonomy ID. This will allow targeting of the taxonomy class even if the title changes
    $vars['classes_array'][] = "taxonomy-id-" . $result['#options']['entity']->tid  ;
    }
}
// MAGIC ENDS HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean with that body tag, but the classes on the node are generated here:

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7

You can add more by implementing yourmodule_preprocess_node($vars) and then add whatever you want to $vars['classes_array']

Comment: I did not put any code anywhere ;) If you want to add classes, create a module, implement the mentioned hook and do something similar to the linked function. Which is already part of Drupal core.